# Scraping information from a script tag using Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape information that is within a script tag on a webpage. I've figured out how to get at the information, but I can't figure out how to manipulate it into a data object.

I'm able to get at the information using document.querySelector(x).innerHTML. Here is the innerHTML that appears (the first part doesn't seem to be formatting as code here).

"
Y = YUI(YUI_CONFIG).use(
    'squarespace-commerce-analytics',

```
function(Y) {
  Y.on('domready', function() {
    Y.Squarespace.CommerceAnalytics.checkoutConfirmed({'id':'12345676','orderNumber':'00065','websiteId':'12345678','purchasedCartId':'1234567','testMode':true,'grandTotal':{'currencyCode':'USD','value':3239,'decimalValue':'32.39','fractionalDigits':2},'grandTotalFormatted':'$32.39','subtotal':{'currencyCode':'USD','value':2300,'decimalValue':'23.00','fractionalDigits':2},'subtotalFormatted':'$23.00','taxTotal':{'currencyCode':'USD','value':204,'decimalValue':'2.04','fractionalDigits':2},'taxTotalFormatted':'$2.04','shippingTotal':{'currencyCode':'USD','value':735,'decimalValue':'7.35','fractionalDigits':2},'shippingTotalFormatted':'$7.35','billingDetails':{'customer':{'address':{'city':'New York','region':'NY','country':'United States'}}},'items':[{'sku':'123456','productName':'This is a Product','unitPrice':{'currencyCode':'USD','value':2300,'decimalValue':'23.00','fractionalDigits':2},'quantity':1}]});
  });
});
```

"

This code shows the innerHTML that I'm getting, and I want each of the data items (id, orderNumber, productName etc.) to be formatted into an object so that I can track ecommerce better using GTM. I'm not sure how to manipulate it in a way that I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace all the `'`s with `"`s, this will be JSON that you can parse, so if you use a regular expression to match `checkoutConfirmed` to the `);`, you can extract the almost-JSON, turn it into JSON, and then parse it:

```js
const html = document.querySelector('script[type="dontexecute"]').innerHTML;
const singleQuotedJSON = html.match(/checkoutConfirmed\((.+?)\);/)[1];
const actualJSON = singleQuotedJSON.replace(/'/g, '"');
const obj = JSON.parse(actualJSON);
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script type="dontexecute">Y = YUI(YUI_CONFIG).use(
    'squarespace-commerce-analytics',

    function(Y) {
      Y.on('domready', function() {
        Y.Squarespace.CommerceAnalytics.checkoutConfirmed({'id':'12345676','orderNumber':'00065','websiteId':'12345678','purchasedCartId':'1234567','testMode':true,'grandTotal':{'currencyCode':'USD','value':3239,'decimalValue':'32.39','fractionalDigits':2},'grandTotalFormatted':'$32.39','subtotal':{'currencyCode':'USD','value':2300,'decimalValue':'23.00','fractionalDigits':2},'subtotalFormatted':'$23.00','taxTotal':{'currencyCode':'USD','value':204,'decimalValue':'2.04','fractionalDigits':2},'taxTotalFormatted':'$2.04','shippingTotal':{'currencyCode':'USD','value':735,'decimalValue':'7.35','fractionalDigits':2},'shippingTotalFormatted':'$7.35','billingDetails':{'customer':{'address':{'city':'New York','region':'NY','country':'United States'}}},'items':[{'sku':'123456','productName':'This is a Product','unitPrice':{'currencyCode':'USD','value':2300,'decimalValue':'23.00','fractionalDigits':2},'quantity':1}]});
      });
    });</script>
```

Now that you have a well-formed object, you can manipulate it however you want. Eg, to extract the `orderNumber`, reference `obj.orderNumber`:

```js
const html = document.querySelector('script[type="dontexecute"]').innerHTML;
const singleQuotedJSON = html.match(/checkoutConfirmed\((.+?)\);/)[1];
const actualJSON = singleQuotedJSON.replace(/'/g, '"');
const obj = JSON.parse(actualJSON);
console.log(obj.orderNumber);
```

```html
<script type="dontexecute">Y = YUI(YUI_CONFIG).use(
    'squarespace-commerce-analytics',

    function(Y) {
      Y.on('domready', function() {
        Y.Squarespace.CommerceAnalytics.checkoutConfirmed({'id':'12345676','orderNumber':'00065','websiteId':'12345678','purchasedCartId':'1234567','testMode':true,'grandTotal':{'currencyCode':'USD','value':3239,'decimalValue':'32.39','fractionalDigits':2},'grandTotalFormatted':'$32.39','subtotal':{'currencyCode':'USD','value':2300,'decimalValue':'23.00','fractionalDigits':2},'subtotalFormatted':'$23.00','taxTotal':{'currencyCode':'USD','value':204,'decimalValue':'2.04','fractionalDigits':2},'taxTotalFormatted':'$2.04','shippingTotal':{'currencyCode':'USD','value':735,'decimalValue':'7.35','fractionalDigits':2},'shippingTotalFormatted':'$7.35','billingDetails':{'customer':{'address':{'city':'New York','region':'NY','country':'United States'}}},'items':[{'sku':'123456','productName':'This is a Product','unitPrice':{'currencyCode':'USD','value':2300,'decimalValue':'23.00','fractionalDigits':2},'quantity':1}]});
      });
    });</script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much! This looks like its close, but there are a couple of things. First, when I console.log(actualJSON) I'm not seeing the double quotes in the console.

Second, it looks like the Object might be formatted weird? I'm not sure. The customer information doesn't seem to be outputting, and when I try obj.sku, its undefined.

Comment: I copied the code to be scraped directly from your question - if the output you're getting is not the same as when you press "Run code snippet" in the answer above, then the code on the actual site must be different from what you've posted..?

Comment: I thought about that, but even when I copied your <script> tag as the HTML that I'm pulling, codePen still seems to format the Object differently than your answer above. I'll see if I can add the output to my question.

Comment: If you link me to the codepen I can take a look at it too, see what might be causing the discrepancy

Comment: Looks the same to me. Codepen's custom console is different from Stack Snippets' custom console, but the logged object is still fundamentally the same, they're just presented differently. Examine the logged objects in the browser console, and they should be identical

Answer (score 0):

Hi developer arriving from a Google search! CertainPerformance's answer is the best answer for general scraping, but if all you care about is getting this particular Squarespace order detail information on a given Order Confirmation page, here's the fast track to the object you want:

```
Y.Squarespace.CommerceAnalytics._yuievt.events["commerceTrack:commerce-checkout-confirmed"].details[0]
```

Have fun! =)